# Silverlight - WCF: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight

My silverlight app consumes my wcf service. One of the objects has a collection property. In the service side the property is a List

Everything was working fine all these days, I'm not sure what I did, where I made any changes but suddenly my silverlight app throws this error. I tried using a windows forms application, it's the same.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<someobject> to someobject[]
```

Usually when it happens I right click on the service and 'Configure service reference' and change the collection type from the dropdown to observable collection, but this time it doesn't seem to work. What's puzzling me is, it was working for more than 6 months now, and suddenly today it won't work.

I tried getting previous versions of my wcf web.config file but nothing seems to fix it.

======================
updated:

I think I found what's going wrong, I just don't know why it won't work this way.

Originally I had my Task class like this

```
public class Task
{
    Public List<TaskItem> Items { get; set; }   
    //Public TaskItems Items { get; set; }  
}
```

---

Now I have like this:

```
public class Task
{
    //Public List<TaskItem> Items { get; set; } 
    Public TaskItems Items { get; set; }    
}

public class TaskItems : List<TaskItem>
{

}
```

---

I think if I can see TaskItems object in my silverlight app, I should be good. But for some reasons it's not showing up.
On the client side I am referencing like this:

```
task.Items = new ObservableCollection<TaskItem>();
```

Comment: Can you post the config of the wcf service? and the code of the service

Comment: I updated my question. I think the problem is in the inheritance part, but I don't know why would it matter.

Comment: have you tried explicitly adding DataContract and CollectionDataContract attributes where appropriate?

Comment: These classes are not in the interface, still it's accessible on the client. I tried adding DataContract attribute, it wouldn't take it since it's not on interface file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `[Serializable]` atributte.

Comment: didn't work :( not sure what else change I did, it's driving me crazy